# How do I use an item from a looped array in BigQuery to run a query multiple times?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that uses a `last_value` function to fill in missing values on days that were not recorded by our sales systems (due to no sales being made).  I need these days in the database to capture the `0` sales for our models.  When I use the `last_value` function with more than one item, the function fails to work as designed and I can't use it to 'fill down' values as I'd like.

That said, I thought of using a loop to loop over items in the query.  When I try to use an array in our `BigQuery` data table to run our query, I get the following error:

```
Query error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, STRUCT<f0_ STRING>. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [215:5]
```

Using the below query as an example, how would I use each value in my array in a `where` statement filter?  I'm using the last line in the `where` statement as the desired filter from the array.

See example query:

```
DECLARE row_count INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE item_vector_array ARRAY<STRING>;
Set item_vector_array = ARRAY(Select DISTINCT(fcast_item) as fcast_item from `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_curation.sales_history_summary`);

FOR item IN (Select * from UNNEST(item_vector_array))
DO
SELECT   
location.fcmicro_corp_cd
,sales_history.ord_dt
,sales_history.fcast_item
,location.iso_loc_type
,MAX(item_master.GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC) as glbl_bus_ln_desc
,MAX(item_master.GLBL_CTGRY_DESC) as glbl_ctgry_desc
,MAX(item_master.GLBL_SUB_CTGRY_DESC) as glbl_sub_ctgry_desc
,MAX(item_master.GLBL_PRDCT_IND_CUT_DESC) as glbl_prdct_ind_cut_desc
,MAX(item_master.ITEM_DESC) as item_desc
,c.intro_dt
-- ,IFNULL(tna.ADJ_TNA, 0) as ADJ_TNA
-- ,IFNULL(tna.TNA, 0) as TNA
,IFNULL(promo_base.promotion_type, 'regular_item') as promotion_type
,CAST(item_price.DCOST_USD as FLOAT64) as dcost_usd
,CAST(item_price.DCOST_LOCAL as FLOAT64) as dcost_local
,sum(sales_history.ord_qty) as ord_qty
,sum(sales_history.demand_usd) as demand_usd

FROM `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_curation.sales_history_summary` sales_history


LEFT OUTER JOIN `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_mdm.location` location 
on sales_history.loc = location.loc

LEFT JOIN `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_MASTER` item_master 
on sales_history.fcast_item = item_master.ITEM_NO
and location.fcmicro_corp_cd = item_master.CORP_CD
and item_master.CORP_CD = "180"

LEFT JOIN (select distinct(ITEM_NO), MAX(INTRO_DT) as intro_dt, corp_cd 
        from gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_MASTER
        where corp_cd = "180"
        group by ITEM_NO, corp_cd) c
        on sales_history.fcast_item = c.ITEM_NO

left join `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_PRICE` item_price
on sales_history.fcast_item = item_price.ITEM_NO
and PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', CONCAT(CAST(item_price.YR AS STRING), '-', LPAD(CAST(item_price.MO AS STRING), 2, '0'), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(item_price.YR, item_price.MO, 1), MONTH))) AS STRING), 2, '0'), 'T00:00:00')) = PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from sales_history.ord_dt) AS STRING), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from sales_history.ord_dt) AS STRING), 2, '0'), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR from sales_history.ord_dt), EXTRACT(MONTH from sales_history.ord_dt), 1), MONTH))) AS STRING), 2, '0'), 'T00:00:00'))
and item_price.CORP_CD = "180"

left join promo_base as promo_base
    on sales_history.fcast_item = promo_base.ITEM_NO

WHERE
right(sales_history.fcast_item, 3) not in ('PAT', 'SVC')
and sales_history.fcast_item <> ""
and location.fcmicro_corp_cd = "180"
and sales_history.ord_dt <= DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
and sales_history.fcast_item = item


GROUP BY
fcmicro_corp_cd
,sales_history.ord_dt
,sales_history.fcast_item
,location.iso_loc_type
,c.intro_dt
,item_price.DCOST_USD 
,item_price.DCOST_LOCAL
,promo_base.promotion_type
-- ,ADJ_TNA
-- ,TNA

ORDER BY
location.iso_loc_type
,sales_history.fcast_item
,sales_history.ord_dt

END FOR;
```

Comment: How does the first paragraph relate to the balance of the question - are you looking for a way to generate the missing zero sales records? i.e. what is the real issue here? (also, why would you want to run that expensive query multiple times? what do you do with the output of each run? seems weird to me, why not do just one run?)

Comment: Good question. I tried to communicate why I'm using a loop.  The first paragraph was meant to state that when I try one run, the last_value clause does not function as designed.  When I query one item at a time, it does.  If I can figure out how to do this in one run, I'd love to know.

Comment: As a general rule loops are anti-patterns in SQL. It is more efficient to run 1 SQL query to generate the all the missing records, and it is almost certainly possible this can be done

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a STRING with a STRUCT in your WHERE clause, here:

```
and sales_history.fcast_item = item
```

`sales_history.fcast_item` is a STRING, but `item` is a STRUCT coming from the UNNEST operation.

You need to access the specific field of the STRUCT that you want to compare **e.g**:

```
and sales_history.fcast_item = item.fcast_item
```

---

**btw**

"select distinct" is NOT a function call so the parentheses in this: `SELECT DISTINCT (ITEM_NO)` are redundant - they are simply ignored.

Furthermore using "select distinct" is redundant anyway as you are already using "group by" on that same column.

I would suggest using this sub-query instead:

```
SELECT
      ITEM_NO
    , MAX(INTRO_DT) AS intro_dt
    , corp_cd
FROM gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_MASTER
WHERE corp_cd = '180'
GROUP BY ITEM_NO, corp_cd
```

nb: I have added `corp_cd` into the group by clause as a precaution only. Whilst `corp_cd` is a constant due to the where clause, if that were ever to change your sub-query could cause an error.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I'm new to the loops in SQL.  I'm only used to basic queries and sub-queries.  That said, when I change my where statement to item.fcast_item, I get an error that states `Query error: Field name fcast_item does not exist in STRUCT<f0_ STRING> at [216:37]`  But in my `set` command for item_vector, I thought I named it fcast_item.